# How to search characters separated by whitespace?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a text file containing normal strings. That is characters like these, delimited by white space.

I wanted to search for 'A' followed by a space.

How can I do this?

Comment: Do you mean you want the positions of all of the spaces in the file?

Comment: Your question is way to vague.

Answer (score 1):

By using `import RE` your can do searches in text that match regular expressions.

If your are looking at the positions the space occurs you could try the following

```
import re
with open("text", "r") as text:
    [i.start() for i in re.finditer(" ", text.read()]
```

This will return a list of the positions where a space occurs.

If your were explicitly looking for when an 'A' was followed by a space you would do this with

```
import re
with open("text", "r") as text:
    [i.start() for i in re.finditer("A ", text.read()]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with open("testfile", "r") as testfile:
    positions = [i for i, x in enumerate(testfile.read()) if x == ' ']
print positions
```